# Web crawling class hidden fields

Tags: java, jsoup, hidden-field

I'm new to this.  After testing several websites with my crawler I came across the following:

```
<div class="originalCurrencyInformation">                            
<label class="Hidden original-price">Price: £500</label>
```

Note the class:Hidden rather than type="Hidden".  How can I retrieve the price using any library but my preference is Jsoup.

Here is an example snippet of code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.org")
                            .timeout(3000).get();
    Elements tags = doc.select("div.originalCurrencyInformation > Label.original-price");
    for(Element tag: tags){
                   System.out.println(tag);
    }
```

**Update**

I have tried Label.Hidden original-price and Label.Hidden.original-price but the value returns null, that's what I'm getting

Comment: You already seem to have the means to parse html/xml. `class="Bla"` is just a class name mostly used to address css style-sheets or as identifiers for JavaScript it's just a name don't mix it up with `style="visibility:hidden"` or `type="hidden"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the `original-price` is not in a div, so it's not clear why you are looking for `div.original-price`. You can use:

`doc.select("div.originalCurrencyInformation > label.Hidden.original-price")`

To select the labels that have both the "Hidden" and "original-price" classes.

You can then use:

`tag.text()`

To get just the text from an element.

Comment: I have tried label.Hidden.original-price but it returns null when I use .html() or text()

Comment: Sorry my bad.  On closer inspection the site changes its pricing tag for different pages.  It looks like I need to find the attribute value and see if it contains price then print the html.  I'm sure Oncaphillis is right and it doesnt matter if class has hidden inside it

Comment: If the tag is different, you can just use ".Hidden.original-price" to match any element that has those class names, or just ".original-price" if you don't care about "Hidden".

Comment: @Alex I just tried a test with JSoup 1.8.1 and it didn't return `null` with `.text()`, but that may have just been because of the changing tags you mention above.